# Присутствие запятой меняет смысл (см.)?

Tags: авторская-пунктуация, диалектизмы

> И творила я тогда безнаказанно, уже какие-то акробатические этюды.

Мне кажется, что запятая случайная, но если её можно объяснить, трогать не буду.

Творить = вытворять? Так говорят?

Comment: Очень хороший вопрос!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы обстоятельство обособила, а то предложение не очень корректно читается:

*И творила я тогда, **безнаказанно**, уже какие-то акробатические этюды.*

*Творить этюды* — **авторский вариант** (скорее всего, высокий стиль с ироническим подтекстом). Нейтральное сочетание: *выполнять упражнения, этюды*.

**ТВОРИТЬ**, (св. сотворить). 1. (что). Высок.  Создавать, созидать в процессе творческой деятельности материальные или духовные ценности.  Подлинный актёр всегда творит.

Comment: Речь о, мягко говоря, эротическом, во всяком случае - амурном. Ну что-то в этой сфэре акробатическое исполнялось-вытворялось.

Comment: Я думаю, что это непринципиально. Наречие всё-таки лучше обособить.

Comment: Угу. Хорошо пошло.)))